# "unknown top level operator: $OR" error in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, match, pipeline, aggregation

I tried to run this query to get the count of PostGraduate and Graduate document.
I am getting the error : "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $OR"
Please let me know what is the mistake here.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
{ "$match": { "$OR": 
[{Education: "Graduate"}, {Education: "PostGraduate"}] 
} },
{ $group: { _id: "$Education",  TotalCount: { $sum: 1 } } }
]
)
```

This is the collection:

```
{ Education: "Graduate" },
{ Education: "Graduate" },
{ Education: "Graduate" },
{ Education: "PostGraduate" },
{ Education: "PostGraduate" },
{ Education: "UnderGraduate" },
{ Education: "UnderGraduate" }
```

Comment: Try lower case `$or`

Comment: using $or in lower case worked , thanks